# ASP.NET Page events calling twice

Tags: asp.net

I have code in one of my pages which is as given below:

```
<asp:button id="btnTest" runat="server" onclick="btnTest_click" />
<div class="TomasForm">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <asp:Label ID="LineL" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Lines" Text="<%$ FieldLabelResources:Units, Line, false %>" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="Lines" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Lines_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:Common, SelectOne %>" Value="-1" />
                </asp:DropDownList >
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My issue is when I change the Lines dropdownlist value, the page(page_load and Lines_SelectedIndexChanged events) is getting called twice.
The page is behaving normal when I click btnTest button.

Could anyone let me know why this is happening??

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: Could you please provide the code ..

Comment: You might want to paste the code from your SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

Comment: If you set the selected value in your page load eventhandler(or other life cycle event)  then you will cause the changed event to fire again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the AutoPostBack to False in your DropDownList.

Comment: but if the OP wants the page to postback when the dropdownlist is changed (which is fine), it shouldn't be firing the page events twice...

Answer (score 0):

You should set the AutoPostback to false for dropdown list and in code,make sure you write the condition like this in Page_Load
if (!isPostBack())
{
// Write your code, it will work only once
}

Comment: But, I want to postback when the dropdown value is changed.

Comment: This is the postback code I am using:                            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Lines.DataSource = TomasContext.Current.GetTubeLines();
                Lines.DataBind();
               
            }
        }